# Google Cloud SQL: how to enable GDAL drivers with PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, postgis, google-cloud-sql

My goal is to is to run PostGIS' `ST_AsGDALRaster` function. With no configuration, PostGIS 2.2+ will error out:

```
ERROR: rt_raster_to_gdal: Could not load the output GDAL driver
```

This is all fine and expected. However with GCP's Cloud SQL, I'm unable to set the PostGIS flags that properly enable the drivers. I've attempted the following:

Setting via gcloud:

```sh
gcloud instances patch $instance \
    --database-flags 'postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers=ENABLE_ALL'
```

which errors out with the following:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.patch) HTTPError 404: Flag requested cannot be set.
```

Attempting to set it via SQL set via

```
SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';
```

which shows the following in Cloud SQL's error log:

```
WARNING: permission denied to set parameter "postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers"
```

---

Is there a recommended way to proceed with generating raster images from Cloud SQL + PostGIS?

Comment: What do you mean by generating a faster image?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work but you can give it a try: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229100/google-cloud-sql-lacks-raster2pgsql

Comment: @llompalles: PostGIS allows you to generate images from geometry (vectorized) and images (raster) in a variety of formats, e.g. geotiff/jpeg.

@lusitanica: `raster2pgsql` and loading the data in work fine. It's just the querying of it in image form.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you created a post in [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/131229722). I'm currently working for Google Cloud Platform Support. Sadly nowadays is not possible to modify this flag, but I routed this information to the Cloud SQL engineering team and they will evaluate this feature request. However, I cannot promise you any ETA for this feature to be implemented. I recommend you to stay tuned [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/131229722), any updates will be published there.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to set this flag?

Cloud SQL is a fully managed database service that provides easy ways to automatize tasks such as replication, back-up, maintenance etc... This comes at the cost of losing some control over the database configuration, for instance you can not set the value for all the flags. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags) you can find the list of the supported flags for Cloud SQL.

Besides that, there is a newer [PostGis version (2.3) supported in Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#postgis).

Comment: He's trying to use one of PostGIS family of extensions `postgis_raster` that is not available.

Comment: That's correct. And you need to set the environment flag -- see https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_gdal_enabled_drivers.html